How to wait on results of async functions?
I have the following code:
async function seedDb() {
  let users: Array<Users> = [ ... ];
  applications.map(async (user) => await prisma.user.upsert(
    { create: user, update: {}, where: { id: user.id } }));
}

async function main() { 
  await seedDb(); 
  await seedDb2();  // This requires the update in seedDb() to have completed
}

The issue is that there other seedDb functions (e.g. seedDb2) which rely on the users being present in the database before running. But while I start all the updates in seedDb, I do not actually wait (in the sense of blocking) until those functions finished.
What I would like to do is to block until all the async functions spawned by the map return. How do I achieve this?

I don't fully understand how await works. I get that it allows to interrupt execution and waits in that context until the promise is fulfilled, but how do you make it actually block execution? Something like threads.join()?
In C++ for example I would create threads that update the database and then join all of them at the end before returning from seedDb. What is the recommended way of doing this in typescript?
Using return await Promise.all(applications.map(async (user) => await prima.user.upsert(...)) (suggested by a linked so question) seems to me to be incorrect too - different functions (seedDb2) might still be running before the promises spawned by seedDb are finished, which is what I am trying to avoid.
[0] Side question - what is the point of using await Promise.all()? Doesn't Promise.all already resolve the promise and return the actual type, why are we calling await again?

Using Promise.all is correct, unclear what your problem with that is. It also returns a promise, hence you need to await or return it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

@jonrsharpe how does Promise.all help? Let's say seedDb runs. It awaits Promise.all(). Since this is all async, other functions can run in the meanwhile. So seedDb(); seedDb2() means that the DB updates spawned by seedDb2 can already run while seedDb() is still running (or rather, awaiting the result of Promise.all). No?

We can't see where you're using seedDb, so it's hard to say. Are you not awaiting the promise it returns at the calling site?

Yes I am. The code is basically
async function main() { await seedUser(); await seedProducts(); }
Where seedProducts depends on the values that seedUsers has put in the database. But the point is that await does not block execution - it says 'when you actually need the thing I return, then wait' but in this case I don't need anything that it returns - the only side effects are updates to the database. How do I "await" side effects on the database?

...why do you think upsert returns a promise?! By awaiting that, you're awaiting the side effect, it doesn't resolve until the DB updates. Have you actually had a problem here?

@jonrsharpe upsert does return a Promise, see my answer for the actual reason why his code didn't work.

@jonrsharpe Yes, if I run those functions, the database complains that I there are missing foreign keys. If I run those functions one at a time (by commenting the rest out), everything works fine. :/
I guess the point is that await does not block execution, right? It just says 'I will wait whenever you need this value', but in the meanwhile the rest of the code runs. If that value is not needed, then you can run in trouble like now?
I mean otherwise what's the point of doing await db.upsert() - the map will run sequentially anyway?

@JulienRheinbach I know it returns a promise, otherwise I'd be pretty unlikely to ask the OP why they think that's so. Per their comment above their caller was already apparently async, and the question makes it clear they're already aware of Promise.all.

Please give a [mre] to describe the actual problem you're having, then.  Currently the answer to the question you've posted is in the question.

@Heremit The point is to make sure that the users exist in db before executing another Promise. Let me put it this way: By using await, all you're doing is calling .then on the promise, so you're executing a callback whenever the Promise is fulfilled, meaning once the db users have been created, THEN create something else that relies on users. You're waiting for the db to create the users. async-await or Promises in general are NOT like threads, they are not used to run stuff in parallel, JS runs on a single thread.

Not sure what the question is here, await Promise.all(applications.map would be the correct way to do this since you are also awaiting seedDb which contains it. I don't understand why you assume it's not the correct thing to do. Await does not block execution, it simply "suspends" the function until the promise is resolved. Other async operations will still run (but will respect the awaited order), so it works best when your app is async all the way down

Let's say you have a function main() that calls seedUsers() and seedComments()  which requires the users to be present.
What you can do is make your main function async (which simply means it's going to be a Promise) and use await to make sure that the seedUsers() function finished executing before running seedComments():
async function seedUsers() {
    let users: Array<Users> = [ ... ];
    // You must return a single Promise using Promise.all or use Promise.all in the main() function
    return Promise.all(applications.map(async (user) => await prisma.user.upsert(
      { create: user, update: {}, where: { id: user.id } })
    ));
}

async function main() {
  // await blocks execution of the Promise until it is fulfilled 
  await seedUsers();
  // this will run after seedUsers has finished
  await seedComments();
}

The reason your previous code did not work is because you used .map in your seedDb() function but never returned or used the Promises. .map is supposed to transform an array into something else, in your case to transform into Promises, then we create a single Promise using Promise.all that resolves once each Promise of the Promise[] is fulfilled.
Check out Promises on MDN where it also states:

Note that JavaScript is single-threaded by nature, so at a given instant, only one task will be executing, although control can shift between different promises, making execution of the promises appear concurrent. Parallel execution in JavaScript can only be achieved through worker threads.


Thank you for your answer! Does await() block execution? If that was the case, wouldn't you block and wait already in the arrow function used to call map()? We are waiting there too, so when the function is called with the first user, await blocks execution and we wait until the first function completes - negating the effect of having an async function in the first place. No?

JS runs on a single thread, so you're never actually "blocking" code execution, you're just using callbacks on the event loop.

A Promise just describes a value that is unknown right now but might have a value later on. async-await is a nicer syntax, but actually just creates a Promise like new Promise((fulfill, reject) => ...)). Hope that makes more sense
